# Not able to run vba automatically while selecting value from list box

Tags: jquery, excel, vba, excel-2010

I have made a list box using data validation and put values inside as 1,2. And my expectation is that whenever I select 1 from the list box the rows from 4 to 8 should hide and when I select 2 it should hide from rows 5 to 8.

This is happening, but every time I have to go to developer tab and select the option "macros" and select the option of hiding and run it to do the job. My expectation is that as soon as I will select the value from the list box the macro should run.

I am using excel 2010. My code is as follows:

```
Sub hide()
If Range("A1").Value = 1 Then
Range("4:8").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("A1").Value = 2 Then
Range("4:8").EntireRow.Hidden = Fase
Range("5:8").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on your **Listbox**, and select "**assign Macro**"

On the new "assign macro" window, look for your macro **hide**, select it and click **OK**.

This should assign your macro to the listbox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The list box is created using the Data Validation tab. And my expectation is that as soon as I select any value from that list box the rows should hide.

Regards
Tuhin.